# How does Spark build its classpath?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, classpath

Could you share any knowledge on Exactly how spark build its classpath and determine which jars would be available on the driver/executors at runtime?

Here is what I can gather, so please let me know what I am missing or if I misunderstood. There doesn't seems to be a single authoritative documentation on the matter.

also ... the more important question is, does the `Thrift JDBC/ODBC server` use the same approach?

#### Driver

- value of `--jars` to `spark-submit`
- `--packages` to `spark-submit` and `spark-shell`
- the app jar argument to `spark-submit` (the uber jar)
- `--driver-class-path` to `spark-submit`
- `SPARK_HOME/lib`
- `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`
- `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as determined by `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hadoop-env.sh`
- Any `spark.driver.extraClassPath` that find its way to `SparkConf`

#### Executor

- Same as the Driver?
- Any `spark.executor.extraClassPath` that find its way to `SparkConf`

Am I missing anything? Is this consistent across `spark-submit` and the spark daemons? (such as the Thrift server or `spark-shell`).

Comment: Not sure what version you are using, but don't forget the `--packages` option for `spark-shell` and `spark-submit`, which takes in maven coordinates and manages all the dependencies for you. That parameter is a godsend.

Comment: Ah yes I will add that as well